# Find out what superclasses contain property or method implementations

Tags: oop, matlab

If I have properly documented a method or property, I can find out where it was defined by typing `help class/method`, which will tell me `Help for class/method is inherited from superclass otherclass`.
Often, this means there is a method definition there too, but not necessarily (I might implemented an abstract method without re-documenting it).

In the general case, how can I find out what superclass(es) define a particular property or method?

I'd like to know because I'm refactoring my code.

NB: I'm using `classdef`-files and all my classes are `handle` classes, should it be relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `?` character you can find out meta data about your class: `lst = ?yourClass`

in `lst.PropertyList(1).DefiningClass` you will find where the property on index 1 originates from.

in `lst.MethodList(1).DefiningClass` you will find where the method on index 1 originates from.