# Jump to method definition regardless of class it is defined in

Tags: matlab, ide, command-prompt

In the MatlabⓇ IDE, is there any easy way to jump to the definition of a particular method, without knowing in what class it is defined?

For self-contained functions, I can type `edit funcname.m`.  The same for classes.  However, the hierarchy of superclasses for a particular class may be large.  By using metaclasses, I can find out [in what class a method was defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15337648/974555), then open the class, and browse to the appropiate definition.  This is a lot more work than it is for self-contained functions.

From the interactive prompt, is there any *direct* way to *either* jump to the definition of a particular method, *or* put a breakpoint in this method (so that executing it will cause the editor to jump to the definition)?

Answer (score 6):

Actually in MATLAB's IDE you can *move between functions within a file.*
If you want to *get more information about a function that you are calling in your code*, you can use Open Selection (**CTRL+D** with Windows keybindings) to quickly jump to where the function is defined.

Check this link: [MATLAB Spoken Here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2007/03/23/moving-between-functions-within-a-file/)

if you move the cursor on a function in the editor and then press ctrl+D the function will be open in the editor. for methods inside a class you can use 'Go To'.  If the method is defined in the present class.

Comment: Moving between functions works, but not moving between methods across different classes.  I'm looking to jump to a method definition *without knowing in what class it is defined*.  Selecting a method call (such as `obj.meth(a, b)`), Open Selection does nothing at all.  If `meth` is defined in the present class, I can move there with the "Go To" drop-down list, but if it's defined elsewhere, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `which` to locate a function when given specific input arguments.

Say for example we have the following files on the path:

```
>> which -all fun
C:\Users\Amro\Desktop\fun.m
C:\Users\Amro\Desktop\Klass.m    % Klass method
```

#### Klass.m

```
classdef Klass < handle
    methods
        function fun(obj)
            disp('hello from Klass')
        end
    end
end
```

#### fun.m

```
function fun()
    disp('hello from fun')
end
```

Now we can differentiate between the two given what arguments they take:

```
>> o = Klass();
>> which('fun(o)')
C:\Users\Amro\Desktop\Klass.m  % Klass method

>> which('fun')
C:\Users\Amro\Desktop\fun.m
```

Note that in the class method case, we have to use the syntax: `fun(obj, args, ...)` as opposed to `obj.fun(args, ...)`

You can open the editor to the specified function using the `matlab.desktop.editor` API:

```
matlab.desktop.editor.openAndGoToFunction(which('Klass'),'fun');
```