# MATLAB: Jump to definition of class method in a separate file

Tags: matlab, class, methods, editor

How can I jump to a class method definition, which is in a [separate file](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/methods-in-separate-files.html), with a shortcut/menu entry from the Matlab editor?

The usual context-menu -> "Open Class.METHODNAME" (Ctrl+D) does jumps somewhere, but not the right definition.

Using the Matlab command line/window (thanks to @Amro's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18281512/1168315)) jumps to the declaration, not the definition (in the separate file):

```
matlab.desktop.editor.openAndGoToFunction(which('TestClass'),'doSomething');
```

### Example

A class with the overloaded plot function declaration, file `TestClass.m`:

```
classdef TestClass
    properties
        name
    end

    methods
        doSomething(obj, varargin)
    end
end
```

and the implementation of this function in an separate file `doSomething.m`:

```
function doSomething(obj, varargin)
    display(['TestClass'' doSomething() method called. Name: ' obj.name]);
end
```

What I want is: Jump to the `doSomething.m`-definition/implementation in the file "doSomething.m" using Ctrl+D if the cursor is on `doSomething(c)`:

```
c = TestClass;
c.name = 'Alice';
c.doSomething;
```

Comment: What are you using the context menu for? That is always going to use the built-in. If you tell us more about what you're trying to do we can suggest a programmatic alternative.

Comment: @Suever Do you have a reference for that Ctrl+D is always jumping to a built-in function if there's any? I thought it is perhaps a misconfiguration of the paths or something else.

Comment: @Suever The question is more general. Is it now better to understand?

Answer (score 0):

Try double-clicking the method name so that it is highlighted, and then perform `CTRL`+`D`.  That should open it and bring you do the function definition.

I think it is a bug that it is required to highlight the object's method name in order for `CTRL`+`D` to work correctly, whereas for a plain function, simply having the cursor on top of the function name works.

Comment: Thanks for answering years later. Unfortunately, I'm not using Matlab since years. Therefore I can't check it and I'm hesitant to mark your answer as correct. 

Do you maybe have an upstream source documenting this? Then I'm happy to upvote and accept your answer :-)

Comment: No, the only source I have is the response to my bug report, and trying it myself.  Maybe if someone else with MATLAB can corroborate my answer they can comment that here :)